# scanf acting weird

Tags: c, scanf, file-handling

I am learning C file handling. I wrote the following program so the user can enter a student's id and name. But the issue is instead of asking for 2 inputs from the user it is expecting me to input three times... Here is the code. What is the issue?

```
  do
  {
    printf("Enter ID and Name of the student\n");
    scanf("%d\n %s\n",&id, name);
    fprintf(myfile,"%d %s", id, name);
    printf("Are there any more students [y/n]");
  }while(getch()=='y');
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have the \n in the scanf string.

Comment: thanks alot. That's the reason I prefer C++ over C.. there is no hassel of formating in C++

Comment: Some people when confronted with a problem in C, say to themselves, I know, I will just use C++! Now, they have two problems. :-) http://codemines.blogspot.se/2006/08/now-they-have-two-problems.html